# Import comments from numpy.genfromtxt()

Tags: python, numpy

I have data sets which are csv files.
Some of them have comment lines with meta data which are not necessarily the first line.

At this point i import them with numpy.genfromtxt which works great.
However, i would like to be able to import the comment lines as well to scan them for certain criterias.

Is there a simple way to do this?

As an example:

```
''' Beginning of File '''  
' comment tag ' ' Name of colums'  
' comment tag '' Something i don't care about '  
' comment tag '' Something i care about '  
' Data '  
''' End of file '''
```

And then i would like to do something like this:

```
if ' Something i care about ' == ' criteria':
    do_something
```

Comment: Do an ordinary Python file `readlines`.

Comment: Thank you for this Idea!
However, i have to import a lot of those files and they are up several million lines in size. At the end i need to have the data as a numpy array
Is there a good way to transform them into a np array, it seems rather unresourceful to use both routines.
I could limit readlines to a certain number, but since i need to handle data from several people i don't won't to hardcode a line limit into my code.

Comment: `genfromtxt` reads the file line by line, rejects the comments and parses the rest.  It also accepts input from anything that can feed it lines.  I often test code with a list of lines.  You could write a filter function that opens the file (`rb` mode), reads lines, does its thing with the comments, and passes the rest on to `genfromtxt`.